# How to use "cabal-dev ghci" with a non-sandbox, non-global (user?) package?

Tags: haskell, libraries, cabal, ghci, cabal-install

I'm trying out `cabal-dev` for a project I'm working on; the project is a library, and `cabal-dev` does a great job of building a sandboxed version of it - but I'm having trouble with part of my workflow...

I have a script, `scratch.hs`, which (pre-`cabal-dev`) I would load into `ghci` for trying stuff out.  The contents of `scratch.hs` change over time depending on what feature I'm working on, of course.  `scratch.hs` isn't part of the library codebase, it's just my personal scratchspace while I'm working on it.

Now, in order to get a `ghci` session with my sandbox loaded, I can just `cabal-dev ghci`, and then load `scratch.hs` into that.  The problem is that this (by design, and sensibly) excludes my user package database, so if `scratch.hs` references modules from packages which aren't in my library's `build-depends` (which is not unreasonable - it's not part of the library after all), those packages aren't visible, and so I get an error such as:

```
scripts/scratch.hs:8:8:
    Could not find module `Data.Aeson.Generic':
      It is a member of the hidden package `aeson-0.3.2.11'.
      Perhaps you need to add `aeson' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

where, in this case, `scratch.hs` wants to import `Data.Aeson.Generic` but `aeson` is not in my library's `build-depends` (quite properly), but *is* in my user package database.

So how can I work around this?  I can imagine answers in either of these categories, but maybe there are categories I've missed:

1. A way to (selectively) use packages from my user package database in conjunction with the sandbox created by `cabal-dev`.  (Perhaps rolling my own `cabal-dev ghci` style script?)
2. A suggestion on how to improve my workflow so the problem just goes away.

I know I could just install the package globally, but I'm reluctant to pollute my global package database in this manner (and `cabal-dev` discourages this explicitly).

Many thanks for all advice.

Comment: I wonder... can you :set -package from within ghci? (Or whatever the name of the option is that chooses your package database?)

Comment: *slaps forehead* - why didn't I think of that?

Yes, that works - thanks.  I can even add it to `.ghci` and have it happen automatically.  Thanks, Daniel!

Comment: Oops, tell a lie. No, that doesn't work.  It appeared to work earlier, but that was because my project's test-suite uses aeson, so it _was_ referenced in my .cabal file and thus brought in to the sandbox though not, it seems, implicitly loaded by `cabal-dev ghci`, which is why I needed `:set -package aeson` to load it.  If I remove that, then in fact `:set -package aeson` _doesn't_ load the user package database version ("`cannot satisfy -package aeson`"), so I'm back where I started (except that everybody who's viewed this page in the last 3 hours thinks the problem is solved).

Comment: Looking at the GHC manual, it turns out that the flag I meant is called -package-conf, not -package. However, I just tested it, and that doesn't seem to work, either. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is just to install the things that you need into the sandbox. For example, if you need aeson for your interactive script:

```
~/myproject$ cabal-dev install aeson
~/myproject$ cabal-dev ghci
```

Then `:set -package aeson` should work in `ghci`.

If that's inadequate, you have a lot of dependencies you want to use from your user package database, and you don't need `ghci` to be invoked with the other flags that your cabal file sets for invoking `ghc`, then you can invoke non-sandboxed `ghci` with access to the packages from the sandbox as well as your user and global packages. For example (for GHC 7.0.3):

```
~/myproject$ GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=./cabal-dev/packages-7.0.3: ghci
```

(Note both the colon at the end of the `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH` and the space between that and `ghci`.)

Comment: Awesome - many thanks.  The second suggestion is working for me. :-)

(Any idea what happens if sandbox and user have the same package installed, btw?)

The first suggestion also looks good (maybe better) but isn't viable for me at this time: there's a bug in `double-conversion` (a dependency of `blaze-textual`, which is a dependency of `aeson`) which prevents it being used with `ghci`; there is a workaround but [it doesn't work with cabal-dev](https://github.com/mailrank/blaze-textual/issues/4) so I won't be able to install `aeson` into my sandbox at this time.

Comment: Works with cabal 1.18 sandbox feature too with a little change: `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.4.1-packages.conf.d: ghci`